# Change Trace Message in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, trace

In ASP.NET Web Forms we can use the TraceContext.Write* family of methods to output contents to the trace. It is also possible to add custom listeners through system.diagnostics/trace/listeners. One of the base listener classes is WebPageTraceListener. I overrode this class, registered it in web.config and modified the WriteLine method so as to add custom text before the message parameter before I call the base implementation, however, the text that goes to the trace is always the original, not the modified one. Yes, ASP.NET is running my method, I can place a breakpoint there.
So, the question is: is there a way to change the output that goes to the trace page (trace.axd)?

Comment: Trace.axd displays info from a default listener, but you can add your own listeners for other purposes (like logging etc).Not sure if there's a way of intercepting all trace messages to modify them, but that would be done when they're written - not when they're listened to (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 1):

Trace.axd displays info from a default listener, but you can add your own listeners for other purposes (like logging etc).

Not sure if there's a way of intercepting all outgoing trace messages to modify them, but that would be done when they're written - not when they're listened to (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Thanks, what I want is to change the default listener.